# Typescript make function return different types for different inputs

Tags: typescript

I am working on a Typescript project and have a function that returns one value when an input is true and another one when an input is false. The problem is that these two possible return values are two different types, and I have no idea how to properly have Typescript handle that.

The function is sort of like this:

```js
function example(input: boolean): number | string {
  return input ? "string" : 0
}
```

As you can see, I tried using a union type, but this just forces me to do a type check later, which is not the behavior that I want. I am trying to get it so when `input` is `true`, the return type will be `string`, and when `input` is `false`, the return type will be `number`. So far everything that I have tried has not been working.

Thanks in advance for any help you guys can provide!

Comment: You know, this question probably doesn't make sense, because to do this it means you know the value of `input` at compile time, so it's essentially a hard coded value, so you already know if it's true or false, so you can just have an if statement in the parent code.

Comment: In the actual code, there are multiple parameters and `input` controls the format of the output. I just didn't want to post all of that because it isn't necessary for the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [function overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads):

```js
function example(input: true): string;
function example(input: false): number;
function example(input: boolean): number | string {
  return input ? "string" : 0
}
```

Comment: beat me to it  2 more to go...

Answer (score 1):

you should use generics like this:

```
function example<Type>(input: boolean): Type {
  return input ? "string" : 0;
}
```

then:

```
let output = example<string>(true);
```

Comment: I think you mean `input: boolean` and not `input: Type`, since `input: Type` wouldn't work

Comment: yes boolean is correct!